# using itemgetter to get the max of a list of objects

Tags: python, sorting, max

I have a list of objects :

```
my_list = [{id : 1, value1: 30, value2: 40}, {id : 2, value1: 20, value2: 50}]
```

and I want to get the the max between the two dict (my key must be max (value1 and value2)  )

I'm using max with getitem but i'm struggling to get this working :

```
my_new_list = max(my_list, key=max([itemgetter("value1", "value2")]))
```

expected output :

```
{id : 2, value1: 20, value2: 50}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itemgetter` returns a callable that must be applied to an object from your list.

```
my_new_list = max(my_list, key=lambda obj: max(itemgetter("value1", "value2")(obj)))
```

If you didn't need to call `max` on the result, the `itemgetter` value itself would be a valid `key` argument itself.

---

Ideally, Python would have composition operators of some kind for chaining functions together, in which case you could write something like

```
my_new_list = max(my_list, key=max ∘ itemgetter("value1, "value2"))
```

where `∘` is a hypothetical operator defined something like

```
def __compose__(self, f):  # ∘
    return lambda x: self(f(x))
```

---

In fact, in [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org) (a superset of Python for functional programming, which compiles to pure Python) there *are* such operators:

```
my_new_list = max(my_list, key=max .. itemgetter("value1", "value2")
my_new_list = max(my_list, key=max <.. itemgetter("value1", "value2")
```

The former is similar to traditional function composition; the latter explicitly indicates the *direction*, as if you were piping values from one function to the next. There is also a `..>` operator, for "reversing" the direction of the pipe.

```
my_new_list = max(my_list, key=itemgetter("value1", "value2") ..> max)
```

Comment: yeaah !! worked for me thanks a lot for your explanation; itemgetter doing a nice job :)

Comment: still waiting for callable tuples

Comment: @wim? Do you mean something like `(f, g)(3) == f(g(3))`? I think resistance to that would come from the fact that it could just as easily mean `(f(3), g(3))`.